# Newspaper-style div alignment with flex-wrap, overflow, without fixed container size

Tags: css, flexbox

I am currently working on an issue with regards to HTML+CSS and reaching the limits on what I know is possible. Here is the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/jwco2sd8/1/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  background-color: red;
}

.item:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.item:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
<div class="item">10</div>
<div class="item">11</div>
<div class="item">12</div>
<div class="item">13</div>
<div class="item">14</div>
<div class="item">15</div>
<div class="item">16</div>
<div class="item">17</div>
<div class="item">18</div>
<div class="item">19</div>
<div class="item">20</div>
<div class="item">21</div>
<div class="item">22</div>
<div class="item">23</div>
<div class="item">24</div>
<div class="item">25</div>
<div class="item">26</div>
<div class="item">27</div>
<div class="item">28</div>
<div class="item">29</div>
<div class="item">30</div>
<div class="item">31</div>
<div class="item">32</div>
<div class="item">33</div>
<div class="item">34</div>
<div class="item">35</div>
<div class="item">36</div>
<div class="item">37</div>
<div class="item">38</div>
<div class="item">39</div>
<div class="item">40</div>
<div class="item">41</div>
<div class="item">42</div>
<div class="item">43</div>
<div class="item">44</div>
<div class="item">45</div>
<div class="item">46</div>
<div class="item">47</div>
<div class="item">48</div>
<div class="item">49</div>
<div class="item">50</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to achieve a newspaper-style ordering of the divs in the example linked. That means that the primary ordering of the items should be "column", but if there is horizontal space, instead of overflowing vertically, items should first be distributed horizontally first - and then if there is not enough space overflow vertically. I want the container to resize dynamically with the browser window, so I cannot set a constant width or height of the container item.

Adding a 'max-height: 25em' to the .container div, simulates what I want to achieve (on my screen):

[image: Example of the intended result]

Is there a way to achieve the desired effect with just HTML/CSS but without media-queries and JavaScript code. I pretty much understand why what I am doing is not working, but I do not know if there are alternatives.

I added a little bit of JavaScript now to do the necessary "space-left" computations and set max-height from there, but I still feel that a pure CSS+HTML solution should work and would be nicer. Are there any other ways that to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the job of [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) where you only define the `column-width` and you keep the `column-count` auto

```css
.container {
  column-width:10em;
}

.item {
  width: 10em;
  display:inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  background-color: red;
}

.item:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.item:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
  <div class="item">18</div>
  <div class="item">19</div>
  <div class="item">20</div>
  <div class="item">21</div>
  <div class="item">22</div>
  <div class="item">23</div>
  <div class="item">24</div>
  <div class="item">25</div>
  <div class="item">26</div>
  <div class="item">27</div>
  <div class="item">28</div>
  <div class="item">29</div>
  <div class="item">30</div>
  <div class="item">31</div>
  <div class="item">32</div>
  <div class="item">33</div>
  <div class="item">34</div>
  <div class="item">35</div>
  <div class="item">36</div>
  <div class="item">37</div>
  <div class="item">38</div>
  <div class="item">39</div>
  <div class="item">40</div>
  <div class="item">41</div>
  <div class="item">42</div>
  <div class="item">43</div>
  <div class="item">44</div>
  <div class="item">45</div>
  <div class="item">46</div>
  <div class="item">47</div>
  <div class="item">48</div>
  <div class="item">49</div>
  <div class="item">50</div>
</div>
```